# Align individual objects in pyOpenGL to create a bigger aggregated object

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I'm trying to create a key object in PyOpenGL using a combination of torus, cylinder and a cuboid. I am able to get these three individual objects separately in the center of the window, but when I try to merge all these objects in a single window, I'm unable to do that.

This is the code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

vertices = (
    (0.75, -0.25, -0.5),
    (0.75, 0.25, -0.5),
    (-0.75, 0.25, -0.5),
    (-0.75, -0.25, -0.5),
    (0.75, -0.25, 0.5),
    (0.75, 0.25, 0.5),
    (-0.75, -0.25, 0.5),
    (-0.75, 0.25, 0.5),
    )

edges = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7),
    )

surfaces = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (3,2,7,6),
    (6,7,5,4),
    (4,5,1,0),
    (1,5,7,2),
    (4,0,3,6),
    )

colors = (
    (1,0,0),
    (0,1,0),
    (0,0,1),
    (0,0,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
    )

def draw_cuboid():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for surface in surfaces:
        x = 0
        for vertex in surface:
            x+=1
            glColor3fv(colors[x])
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for egde in edges:
        for vertex in egde:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

def draw_cylinder():
    glRotatef(1, 1, 1.25, 12.5)
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    quadratic = gluNewQuadric()
    gluQuadricNormals(quadratic, GLU_SMOOTH)
    gluQuadricTexture(quadratic, GL_TRUE)
    gluCylinder(quadratic, 0.15, 0.15, 2.5, 32, 32)

def draw_torus():
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glutWireTorus(0.2, 0.8, 50, 50)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    glutInit()
    display = (800,600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(75, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    glTranslatef(-0.5, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0)

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    glTranslatef(0, 0.5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    glTranslatef(0, -0.5, 0)

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    glRotatef(5, 0, 1, 0)   

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 4:
                    glTranslatef(0, 0, 1.0)
                if event.button == 5:
                    glTranslatef(0, 0, -1.0)


        glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        draw_cuboid()
        draw_torus()
        draw_cylinder()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```

The output I'm getting for this is below.
[output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VJ0013CnbvdwqpafNkxYyRsiTE0593JY/view?usp=sharing)

As you see all the three objects are spawned from the center of the window.

1. How do I change their positions to get a key like object ie, the cylinder(aligned in y axis) in the center with the torus on top of it and the cuboid at the tip of other end?
2. How do I get this key aligned with y axis (constant without rotation by default) and with the press of the space key, I can start/stop rotation of this whole object along y axis?

Comment: You have to move/rotate all objects into their proper location. Use glTranlate glRotate for that

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi I tried this. When I used glTranslate inside cuboid/torus function, all three objects are disappearing from the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glTranslate(0.9, 0, 2)
    draw_cuboid()
    glTranslate(-0.9, 0, -2)

    glRotate(90,1,0,0)
    glTranslate(0,-1,0)
    draw_torus()
    glTranslate(0, 1, 0);
    glRotate(-90, 1, 0, 0)

    draw_cylinder()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(10)
```

[image]

Comment: While this solution works, you can get rid of the 'undo' action by using `glPushMatrix` before the translate/rotate and `glPopMatrix` afterwards.

Comment: Great, can you please share the code when the cuboid is attached at the side of the cylinder in the top region rather than at the very end?

Comment: Yes, just add a bit to the glTranslate(), see updated code

Comment: The usual way to do this is to use [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Tha matrix operations like [`glRotatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml), [`glScale`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml) and [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) define a matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix.
If a transformation has to be applied to an object, then the model matrix can be multiplied to the current matrix. If this transformation should only be applied to the a single object then after the drawing the object, the inverse model matrix can be multiplied to the current matrix. This undoes the transformation.
But that is not intended way to do this.

The common way is to store the current matrix befor the model transformation and to restore it after drawing the object. For this reason, [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) matrices are organized on a stack. The store the current matrix, it can be pushed onto the stack. To restore it, it can be popped from the stack.

Use [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) to store and restore the current matrix. e.g.:

```py
glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

glPushMatrix()
glTranslate(0.9, 0, 2)
draw_cuboid()
glPopMatrix()

glPushMatrix()
glRotate(90,1,0,0)
glTranslate(0,-1,0)
draw_torus()
glPopMatrix()

glPushMatrix()
draw_cylinder()
glPopMatrix()

pygame.display.flip()
```

Note with this it is unnecessary to implement the inverse matrix operations in the reverse order, because `glPopMatrix` is always to "opposite" of `glPushMatrix`.

Further note, there are multiple, different current matrices (see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)). Ecah vertex coordinate is transformed by the model view matrix (`GL_MODELVIEW`) first. After that it is transformed by (`GL_PROJECTION`) the projection matrix.

It is recommended to set the perspective projection matrix ([`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml)) to the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix and the view and model matrix to the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix:

```py
display = (800,600)
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(75, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
```

See also [Scale, Rotate, Translate](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame_opengl/immediate_mode/pygame_opengl_immediate_mode.md#scale-rotate-translate)

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

vertices = ((0.75, -0.25, -0.5), (0.75, 0.25, -0.5), (-0.75, 0.25, -0.5), (-0.75, -0.25, -0.5),
    (0.75, -0.25, 0.5), (0.75, 0.25, 0.5), (-0.75, -0.25, 0.5), (-0.75, 0.25, 0.5))
edges = ((0,1), (0,3), (0,4), (2,1), (2,3), (2,7), (6,3), (6,4), (6,7), (5,1), (5,4), (5,7))
surfaces = ((0,1,2,3), (3,2,7,6), (6,7,5,4), (4,5,1,0), (1,5,7,2), (4,0,3,6))
colors = ((1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,0), (1,1,1), (0,1,1))

def draw_cuboid():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for surface in surfaces:
        x = 0
        for vertex in surface:
            x+=1
            glColor3fv(colors[x])
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for egde in edges:
        for vertex in egde:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

def draw_cylinder():
    glRotatef(1, 1, 1.25, 12.5)
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    quadratic = gluNewQuadric()
    gluQuadricNormals(quadratic, GLU_SMOOTH)
    gluQuadricTexture(quadratic, GL_TRUE)
    gluCylinder(quadratic, 0.15, 0.15, 2.5, 32, 32)

def draw_torus():
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glutWireTorus(0.2, 0.8, 50, 50)

def main():
    glutInit()
    pygame.init()
    glutCreateWindow(b"OpenGL Window") # prevent glutWireTorus OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000034
    
    display = (400, 300)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(75, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    glTranslatef(-0.5, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    glTranslatef(0, 0.5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    glTranslatef(0, -0.5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    glRotatef(5, 0, 1, 0)   

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 4:
                    glTranslatef(0, 0, 1.0)
                if event.button == 5:
                    glTranslatef(0, 0, -1.0)

        glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslate(0.9, 0, 2)
        draw_cuboid()
        glPopMatrix()

        glPushMatrix()
        glRotate(90,1,0,0)
        glTranslate(0,-1,0)
        draw_torus()
        glPopMatrix()

        glPushMatrix()
        draw_cylinder()
        glPopMatrix()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```